# Integrating Python with R

Tags: python, r, interface, integration

1. I am trying to install the appropriate packages to allow easy access to R from Python.
2. From what I understand, I have to use a command called easy_install to install a program called py2
3. But to do that, I have to install easy_install by running a .egg file downloaded as if it were a shell script.

How do I run my downloaded file as if it were a shell scirpt? And once I have done that, if I just run easy_install py2, will the R interface be installed.

Appropriate links are here:

1. http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2_download.html
2. http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall
3. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: If your run `easy_install rpy2` on the command line what happens? What error message is shown.

Comment: Paul: 'invalid syntax'
Mike: OSX

Answer (score 3):

I suggest installing pip, an alternative to easy_install, first.

I am not sure what tools OSX comes with for downloading the bootstrap code for pip (curl, wget), but I assume you have python 2.X installed, which you can check with

```
python --version
```

Run the following python program, by saving this as download.py and then run 'python download.py':

```
import os
import urllib2
from subprocess import call

def download_file_and_run(url):
    basename = os.path.basename(url)
    fp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    open(basename, 'wb').write(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    call(['python', basename])

download_file_and_run('http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py')
download_file_and_run('https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py')
```

now

```
pip --version
```

should give you a version number like 1.1

Now install rpy2 using:

```
pip install rpy2
```

This assumes R is installed, if not the installer will complain with an error:
Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.

Comment: I have version 2.7 installed. Also when I try typing in 'python --version' in the shell I get an invalid syntax 'python' is not defined error. 

Also, when I try to run the code, I get an invalid syntax error at basename = os....

Comment: @H3lue: @Anthon meant to type `python --version` in the bash shell, not in the python interpreter. But you already figured out your version, so it's a moot point.